# Why order by restricted in SQL subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by

On using *order by* in subqueries, an error is thrown:
For example:

```
set rowcount 10
select * from XXX where Col1 in(
    select Col2 from YYY
    order by Col3 desc
)
```

Why is this type of queries restricted in SQL Server?
The error thrown was:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: In this particular case `order by` in subquery is meaningless since you want only to determine is `Col1` in this subset or not - so why bother about order of subset elements? More generally - can you provide any sample of useful `order by` in mentioned database objects?

Comment: In what scenario would a topless ORDER BY in a subquery be useful? Only the outermost  clause matters

Comment: as mentioned above, in your case it is irrelevant the order of the results in the subquery.  Whether data is ordered ascending, descending, or in random order, it has no bearing on the results in the outer query.

Comment: @AlexK. Assume that Col3  in table YYY is a **DateAdded** coulmn. And as I want to select only top 10, I want those with the latest dates. So want to order by the inner query.

Comment: The order of the set passed to `IN ()` is irrelevant, to limit you would use `TOP` which enables the use of `ORDER BY`

Comment: Understand that orderby passed to inner query is irrelevant. But then, how can i get the top 10 records based on the **dateadded** of inner table **YYY**

Comment: If you add `TOP` to your subquery you are allowed to specify `ORDER BY`, so add `TOP`

Comment: Cool. Thats a nice workaround. But still wondering why **orderby** restricted. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, `SET ROWCOUNT` is pretty archaic these days, `TOP` is generally preferred anyway. (And, IIRC, `set rowcount` wouldn't apply to inner clauses anyway, only the final output of a query)

Comment: If `Col1` values are non-unique and/or there are `Col2` values for which no `Col1` value exists then I suspect that there's an actual question lurking in here (I.e. you wouldn't want to find the 10 latest `Col2` values since that might obtain any number of rows from `XXX`). Adding sample data and expected results to the question would make this far clearer though.

Answer (score 6):

### Why?

**Short Answer:**

Because *sets* have no order.

**Longer Answer:**

SQL is an implementation of *[relational calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_calculus)*, which is based on tuple-*sets* (tables, rowsets, etc.). Sets do not an order (unlike the related concept, *lists* which are sets with ordering).

Further, there's (generally) no benefit to applying ordering to a set before the final output, and a considerable amount of harm, because:

- The optimizer can add or remove ordering at any stage of the query execution, as it sees fit, to increase the performance of the query,
- So, it would just be (considerable) extra work,
- And the optimizer might just undo it the next step anyway
- And queries and stages can be done in parallel, as the optimizer sees fits, and this too is generally in conflict with preserving an ordering.
- So applying it earlier, doesn't mean that that order will still be there in a later stage

The only place it commonly makes sense is in the final output, because data has to be transmitted serially there anyway.

The only places it makes sense *before* the final output is for things like `TOP (N)` which needs an ordering to determine which rows are the "Top" rows.

It can also make sense for certain *aggregate* functions, which is why many of them have their *own* `ORDER BY` clauses.  Also for constructing XML results in intermediate stages.